# proving if $[A|b]$ has at least one solution there must be infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

How should i go about solving part (c) of this question? I have computed the reduced row echelon form of the matrix with $U, V$ and $W$ as their columns and i know there is a free variable. However, I'm unsure how to prove that there must be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Can you find two solutions? And if so, can you find a family of solutions between them?

Comment: but does finding two solutions/expressing them as a family of solutions prove the question? I always thought proves should avoid computing a bunch of values

Comment: Well you do have to prove there are _infinitely_ many. What I am suggesting is that given two distinct solutions, you can describe an infinite family of them. And that's enough. You don't have to get _all_ of them.

Comment: so if i describe the family of solutions as a line ( (0,0,0) + t(3,-1,1) ) that is sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

The augmented matrix is
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 5 & 2 & b_{1} \\
    0 & 5 & 5 & b_{2} \\
    1 & 0 & -3 & b_{3}
  \end{bmatrix} 
After row operation the final matrix in Echelon form we get is
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 5 & 2 & b_{1} \\
    0 & 5 & 5 & b_{2} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & b_{3}-b_{1}+b_{2}
  \end{bmatrix} 
Now we assume that the system has a solution then $b_{3}-b_{1}+b_{2}=0$ and let that $z=t$ then solving the equation, get 
$$5y+5z=b_{2}$$
$$y=\frac{b_{2}-5t}{5}$$,
and solving the equation
$$x+5y+2z=b_{1}$$
$$x=b_{1}-b_{2}+3t$$
so the infinite set of solution for the given system will be
$$(x,y,z)=(b_{1}-b_{2}+3t, \frac{b_{2}-5t}{5}, t)$$, where $t$ belongs to the set of real number.

Answer (score 0):

If you've shows that $u$, $v$ and $w$ are dependent that says exactly that there exists a non-zero vector $c$ with $Ac=0$.  Now if $Ax=b$ it follows that $A(x+tc)=b$ for every scalar $t$.